# Transferring collection items for collection with two IEnumerable<T> implementations with reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have this helper method that is designed to transfer collection items from one collection object instance to another.  It works, but I have recently ran into an issue where a particular collection implements at different points `IEnumerable<T>;`.  At one level as `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` and at another `IEnumerable<TValue>`.  In my code below, the declaration of `secondaryCollection` causes it to use the `IEnumerable<TValue>` instance type versus the collectionType declaration finds it as the base `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` type so that I can invoke the `Add()` and `Remove()`.  With this type mismatch though the `Add()` and `Remove()` method invocations fail. I think if I can figure out how to declare `secondaryCollection` as type `IEnumerable<object>` where 'object' is of type `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` and not of just the type `TValue` that this should work without the type mismatch exception (it's actually an argument exception for the `Add()`, `Remove()` methods).  The problem is this is all done in reflection and the types are unknown.  How can I do this?

Here's the current method code:

```
public void MergeCollection(FieldInfo primaryMember, object primaryObject, FieldInfo secondaryMember, object secondaryObject)
    {
        if (primaryMember == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("primaryMember");

        if (primaryObject == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("primaryObject");

        if (secondaryMember == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("secondaryMember");

        if (secondaryObject == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("secondaryObject");

        //Get the collection type and validate
        Type genericType = typeof(ICollection<>);

        Type collectionType = primaryMember.FieldType.GetBaseTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1 && t == genericType.MakeGenericType(t.GetGenericArguments()));

        if (!collectionType.IsAssignableFrom(secondaryMember.FieldType))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Primary and secondary collection types do not match.");

        Type collectionParamType = collectionType.GetGenericArguments()[0];


        //Get the collection invocable methods
        MethodInfo add = collectionType.GetMethod("Add", new Type[] { collectionParamType });
        MethodInfo remove = collectionType.GetMethod("Remove", new Type[] { collectionParamType });

        //Declare the collections
        object primaryCollectionObject = primaryMember.GetValue(primaryObject);
        object secondaryCollectionObject = secondaryMember.GetValue(secondaryObject);

        Type genericEnumerableType = typeof(IEnumerable<>);
        Type enumerableType = primaryMember.FieldType.GetBaseTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1 && t == genericEnumerableType.MakeGenericType(t.GetGenericArguments()));

        IEnumerable<object> secondaryCollection = ((IEnumerable)secondaryCollectionObject).Cast<object>();

        //Transfer the items
        int noItems = secondaryCollection.Count();
        // int noItems = (int)count.GetValue(secondaryCollectionObject);
        for (int i = 0; i < noItems; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                add.Invoke(primaryCollectionObject, new object[] { secondaryCollection.ElementAt(0) });
                remove.Invoke(secondaryCollectionObject, new object[] { secondaryCollection.ElementAt(0) });
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ex)
            {
                //The argument exception can be captured here
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**

Maybe just to add some clarification for what I'm needing help with...  I have a custom collection that's used in a class being evaluated by a method using reflection.  This collection implements IEnumerable twice... `IEnumerable<TValue>` and `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.  Instead of this...

```
IEnumerable<object> secondaryCollection = ((IEnumerable)secondaryCollectionObject).Cast<object>();
```

which ends up using the `IEnumerable<TValue>` because of the `Cast<T>()` operation, I need something where the `secondaryCollection` uses the `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.  And it can't know that the collection originally used two implementations.  Since this line:

```
Type collectionType = primaryMember.FieldType.GetBaseTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1 && t == genericType.MakeGenericType(t.GetGenericArguments()));
```

does identify the correct type, I originally thought it could be used but I'm not sure how.

Comment: why don't you just do `public void MoveItems<T>(ICollection<T> source, ICollection<T> target) { /* code to remove all items from source and add to target without reflection */ }` ?

Comment: I can't because this is just a small part of a process designed to split a larger object (Message) into multiple smaller ones sent across process boundaries.  This entire process is handled via reflection so that it doesn't have to know the specifics (or even if the Message object has a collection let alone its collection type).  This allows me to have Message objects of different types for different purposes.

Comment: The collections probaly imlement multiple IEnumerable<T>, but only one ICollection<T>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you correctly said the issue is with the Cast method. Because you are not passing the proper type in Cast method you are getting wrong IEnumrable. The solution is not to call the Cast method with the type "object", instead use proper type. As you don't have proper type information at compile time you may need to call Cast using reflection, something like this:

```
var castMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
var castGenericMethod = castMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] {  collectionParamType});
secondaryCollection = castGenericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {secondaryCollectionObject})
```

Note: I have just typed the above code in my iPad so there may be some syntax issues.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  We deployed an application update company-wide and my day has been crazy.  I tried this and it does get the collection as the KeyValuePair<,> type.  I can even cast secondaryCollection as an IEnumerable, but as you can see in my example, there's an add.Invoke() and remove.Invoke() designed to add the first item from the secondaryCollection to the primary and then remove that first item.  The ElementAt() is available to IEnumerable<T>, but not IEnumerable.  I can't cast to IEnumerable<object> or I'm back to where I was.  How do I work around this?

Comment: You don't need to cast to IEnumerable<object>,  instead use reflection to get reference to ElementAt method in the same way as we have done for Cast<T> method.

Comment: See this on how to call ElementAt using reflection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948506/how-to-call-extension-method-elementatof-listt-with-reflection

Comment: Thank you Deepak, you answered my question directly.  If you see my response to Ivan below, what's the best way to award points?

Comment: I don,t think u can distribute points among us. It purely your decision to whome you award, but I am glad my solution helped. See this on how points can be awarded:http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Answer (score 1):

Just saw that Zotta brought a similar idea while I was preparing my answer. Here is mine anyway. The easiest way is to have the main implementation in "pure" C# generic method and just call it from reflection. Now the question is how to call a generic method via reflection. There are several SO items regarding that, and so far the easiest way is to use dynamic feature. Here is a sample solution including both dynamic or pure reflection methods (validations skipped) and a simple test:

```
static class Helper
{
    public static void Merge<T>(ICollection<T> source, ICollection<T> target)
    {
        foreach (var item in source) target.Add(item);
        source.Clear();
    }

    #region Using dynamic

    public static void MergeCollection(FieldInfo sourceMember, object sourceObject, FieldInfo targetMember, object targetObject)
    {
        var sourceCollection = sourceMember.GetValue(sourceObject);
        var targetCollection = targetMember.GetValue(targetObject);
        Merge((dynamic)sourceCollection, (dynamic)targetCollection);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Using reflection only

    public static void MergeCollection2(FieldInfo sourceMember, object sourceObject, FieldInfo targetMember, object targetObject)
    {
        var collectionType = targetMember.FieldType.GetInterfaces().Single(
            t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>)
        );
        var itemType = collectionType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        var mergeMethod = MergeMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(itemType);
        var sourceCollection = sourceMember.GetValue(sourceObject);
        var targetCollection = targetMember.GetValue(targetObject);
        mergeMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { sourceCollection, targetCollection });
    }

    private static readonly MethodInfo MergeMethodInfo = GetGenericMethodDefinition(
        (ICollection<object> source, ICollection<object> target) => Merge(source, target)
    );

    private static MethodInfo GetGenericMethodDefinition<T1, T2>(Expression<Action<T1, T2>> e)
    {
        return ((MethodCallExpression)e.Body).Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Test

    class MyCollection1<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, IEnumerable<TValue>
    {
        IEnumerator<TValue> IEnumerable<TValue>.GetEnumerator() { return Values.GetEnumerator(); }
    }

    class MyCollection2<TKey, TValue> : List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IEnumerable<TValue>
    {
        IEnumerator<TValue> IEnumerable<TValue>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> e = this;
            return e.Select(item => item.Value).GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    class MyClass1
    {
        public MyCollection1<int, string> Items1 = new MyCollection1<int, string>();
    }

    class MyClass2
    {
        public MyCollection2<int, string> Items2 = new MyCollection2<int, string>();
    }

    private static FieldInfo GetField<T, V>(Expression<Func<T, V>> e)
    {
        return (FieldInfo)((MemberExpression)e.Body).Member;
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        var source = new MyClass1();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) source.Items1.Add(i + 1, new string((char)('A' + i), 1));
        var target = new MyClass2();
        var sourceField = GetField((MyClass1 c) => c.Items1);
        var targetField = GetField((MyClass2 c) => c.Items2);
        // Merge source into target using dynamic approach
        MergeCollection(sourceField, source, targetField, target);
        // Merge target back into source using reflection approach
        MergeCollection2(targetField, target, sourceField, source);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I've tried these and ended up with a RuntimeBinderException on the dynamic approach when calling the Merge<T>().  I'm not sure why.  If I make both arguments dynamic rather than ICollection<T> and ignore the generic type, it works.  With that in mind, here's the performance difference for 10,000 items: My original code: 63 ms, Dynamic Method: 35 ms, and your version of Reflection: 15 ms.

Comment: What's the best approach for awarding points?  You've helped me improve the process, but Deepak Bhatia answered the question directly.

Comment: Interesting, you really found another way to accomplish the same thing - a dynamic **implementation**. But as you noticed, it would have a similar performance to pure reflection. My goal was to have as much as possible complied code, and just to call it somehow. Since dynamic **binding** to a generic method looks like is not working always, now I think the "reflection only" approach is preferable.
Regarding your question, it's up to you. I'm interested in solving issues that I find challenging. I'm a "performance" guy and always look for the best solution. Glad if that helped you. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This might work (just pass the collections as source and target):

```
public static void MoveItems(dynamic source, dynamic target) {
    MoveItemsImpl(source, target);
}

public static void MoveItemsImpl<T>(ICollection<T> source, dynamic target) {
    foreach(T item in source)
        target.Add(item);
    source.Clear();//optional
}
```

A bit hacky, but worth a try :)