# Create a Generic IEnumerable<T> given a IEnumerable and the member datatypes

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I get an IEnumerable which I know is a object array. I also know the datatype of the elements. Now I need to cast this to an IEnumerable`<T`>, where T is a supplied type. For instance

```
IEnumerable results = GetUsers();
Type t = GetType(); //Say this returns User
IEnumerable<T> users = ConvertToTypedIEnumerable(results, t);
```

I now want to cast/ convert this to IEnumerable`<User`>. Also, I want to be able to do this for any type.

I cannot use IEnumerable.Cast<>, because for that I have to know the type to cast it to at compile time, which I don't have. I get the type and the IEnumerable at runtime.

-
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean, you don’t have the type at compile time? What else would `T` be in your example in `IEnumerable<T>` (second line)?

Comment: If you don't know the type at compile-time then you wouldn't be able to use `typeof` either. You should update your example code.

Comment: Updated the example code to make things more clear.

Comment: unfortunately, your clarification doesn’t really help. You *still* need to know the type `T` at compile time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically Create a generic type for template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67370/dynamically-create-a-generic-type-for-template)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use reflection to call Cast<> with a runtime type. See this answer: [How to call a generic method through reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941263/how-to-call-a-generic-method-through-reflection)

However, at some point you'll still have to know the type of the item at compile time if you ever want to manipulate it as such without reflection. Just having an `IEnumerable<T>` instance cast as an object/IEnumerable still won't really do you any more good than just having the IEnumerable by itself. It's likely that you need to rethink what you're doing.