# Convert generic object list to non-generic type list

Tags: c#, object, generics, reflection

I am trying to convert a `List` of `System.Object` objects to a `List` of strongly typed objects.

Here is the error I am getting:

> Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TestApp.Tsc_Mrc_Step]'.

The purpose is because I am writing a business data layer for my project that all you have to do is name your class and properties the same name as entities in  your database and the data layer will automatically populate referenced tables as types that are declared in the class.

The business data layer uses reflection, generics and objects to deal with all of this.

Below is the code I tried to put a List of objects into a List of known types. The thing is, the object is the known type but I pass it as an object....How do I convert it to the known type without knowing what it is?

```
            bool isCoollection = false;
            Type t = GetTypeInsideOfObjectByTypeName(o, tableName, out isCoollection);

            List<object> objectColl = new List<object>();

            object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
            if (obj != null)
            {
                PropertyInfo[] objectProps = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
                foreach (PropertyInfo op in objectProps)
                {
                    if (HasColumn(reader, op.Name))
                    {
                        op.SetValue(obj, reader[op.Name]);
                    }
                }

                if (isCoollection)
                {
                    objectColl.Add(obj);
                }
            }

            if (isCoollection)
            {
                IEnumerable<object> objs = objectColl.AsEnumerable();

                SetObject(o, objs);
            }
            else
            {
                SetObject(o, obj);
            }
```

Here is SetObject:

```
            public static void SetObject(object parentObject, object newObject)
            {
                PropertyInfo[] props = parentObject.GetType().GetProperties();
                string typeName = newObject.GetType().Name;
                foreach (PropertyInfo pi in props)
                {
                    if (pi.PropertyType.Name.ToLower() == typeName.ToLower())
                    {
                        pi.SetValue(parentObject, newObject);
                    }
                    else if (!pi.PropertyType.IsValueType && !pi.PropertyType.Namespace.ToLower().Contains("system"))
                    {
                        SetObject(pi.GetValue(parentObject), newObject);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: can you post what did you try?

Comment: could you add the code that you use (or at least the snippets that allude to the strongly typed list

Comment: Using reflection _and_ generics together usually means you shouldn't be using _either_.

Answer (score 5):

If you know all of the values are of the required type in a list:

```
List<Object> objects;
List<Cat> cats = objects.Cast<Cat>().ToList();
```

If not all the values are of the type, and you want to weed out the ones that aren't:

```
List<Object> objects;
List<Cat> cats = objects.OfType<Cat>().ToList();
```

Both require LINQ.

If you don't know the type until runtime, you have to use reflection.

[How to call a generic method through reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941263/how-to-call-a-generic-method-through-reflection)

Comment: But all I know is the Type, not the class name :(

Comment: @deccks but... the type IS the class name

Comment: but how could I do this: Type t = GetTypeInsideOfObjectByTypeName(o, tableName, out isCoollection);
                                            IEnumerable<t> cats = objects.OfType<t>().AsEnumerable();

Comment: @deccks Added link to similar answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I accomplished my goal. All thanks to the dynamic variable. I am impressed that I am able to do that using .NET. What do you think? Thanks :)

```
Type t = GetTypeInsideOfObjectByTypeName(o, tableName, out isCoollection);

Type genericListType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(t);

object coll = Activator.CreateInstance(genericListType);

dynamic objectColl = Convert.ChangeType(coll, coll.GetType());

dynamic d = Convert.ChangeType(obj, obj.GetType());

objectColl.Add(d);
```