# Pass table type as T for generic list

Tags: c#, list, entity-framework, generics

I have a table called `myTable`. Using EntityFramework I can create a list of queried `myTable`'s like so:

```
List<myTable> myList = context.myTables.ToList();
```

I want to create a reusable method in a "Utilities" class where I can pass the method a table type and create a List of that type.

Something like:

```
public static void ListFromType(Type suppliedTableType)
{
    List<supliedTableType> myList = new List<suppliedTableType>();
}
```

Comment: What does your question have to do with EF? Do you just want to create an empty list? `var myList = new List<T>();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do won't compile (as I am sure you know)

```
public static void ListFromType(Type suppliedTableType)
{
    List<supliedTableType> myList = new List<suppliedTableType>();
}
```

First off the method is `void` which means it returns nothing, secondly you are using a `System.Type` instance as a generic type parameter which does not work.

When you look at the problem it begs the question, why even do this at all?  You always have to know the type to create an instance of the list, so why not just allocate a List directly all the time?  Why call an ancillary method to simply do:

```
List<myTable> someList = new List<myTable>();
// or to save yourself from typing myTable twice
var someList = new List<myTable>();
```

If you *really* want some fancy Linq that **achieves the same exact thing** you can use `Enumerable.Empty<T>` and call `ToList()` on it:

```
List<myTable> someList = Enumerable.Empty<myTable>().ToList();
```

If your goal is to create Lists based on a `System.Type` variable (as indicated in your non-compiling code sample), you would have to use a mixture of Reflection and other methods of `Enumerable`.  @Camilo  has pointed out a [fairly relevant question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941263/how-to-call-a-generic-method-through-reflection) that could help along those lines.  Your question was tagged with Generics and not Reflection so I don't want to make too many assumptions.

Comment: You *could* add [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941263/how-to-call-a-generic-method-through-reflection) (or a reference to it), to provide another option which would actually solve the problem

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto yeah I am not even sure anymore what the OP wants.  I will add a link in my answer but I won't elaborate too much

Comment: How do you want to consume a generic type constructed with reflection? You need to know the type a compile time anyway to be able to access the list.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes You should be able to access all the types of the DbContext (since this is EF)

Comment: Like I said, I am wanting a reusable method that will create a generic list of type "whichever entity framework table object I pass it"

Comment: @toadfromgrove well you havent really explained _how_ you would be passing the type.  My answer is valid if you are passing `T` parameters, if you want to use a `System.Type` you need to use reflection (but this was tagged with generic so I gave you an answer using generics)

Comment: Yes, you can access all the tables in a generic way through `context.Set<T>`. I was talking about the link given by @CamiloTerevinto describing how to use reflection for generic types.

Comment: @maccettura The sample method I supplied provided the parameter mySuppliedType as Type, but of course that will not work. It's just what I'm trying to mirror. I probably used generics out of context then. I thought any list that used <>'s was a generic list.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes It's certainly possible to use Reflection to consume generic types. How easy is it to write that code is another topic.

Comment: @toadfromgrove: any list using `<>` **is** a generic list; however, it accepts only a type name `List<TypeName>` (which can be a real type of a generic type), not an object of type `Type`, neither one of type `string`.

Answer (score 0):

With EF you have two options (in addition to accessing your named DbSets directly):

1. Generic

   ```
   List<T> myList = context.Set<T>().ToList();
   ```
2. With a `Type` parameter

   ```
   object[] untypedArray = context.Set(typeOfSomeTable).ToArray();
   // or
   List<object> untypedList = context.Set(typeOfSomeTable).ToList();
   ```

With variant 2 you only get untyped objects, since the type is not known at compile time.

Note: Generic collections have the advantage of allowing strongly typed access to their items. "Strongly typed" always means that type compatibility of operations on this type is tested by the compiler, hence, the type must be known at compile time.

Let's assume that you had a method accepting a `Type` parameter. Which type should the list have? We don't know it at compile time.

```
Type type = ...;
WhichTypeShouldWeUseHere list = ListFromType(type);
```